# After partitioning an eclipse project in a few modules build performance degraded

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

The project currently has only 3 modules with following dependencies:

```
main +-> subsystem -> shared
     +-> shared
```

After partitioning around 3.000 classes compilation takes 3 minutes instead of 30 seconds (before partitioning). I would like to split the main project into further modules.
It seems that something causes eclipse to do a full build instead of the usual incremental
build. Ant builds (in separate directories) take approx. 40 secs as before.
I already started over with freshly checked out sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case ProcessMonitor http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx showed that during build many resources were copied from src to bin. This was easy to fix by excluding these directories in the project settings. 
I'm sorry about answering my own question.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try different build order configurations. In the Preferences dialog, find General > Workspace > Build Order. Maybe if you set your shared project to be first in the build order it might speed things up.

Good luck.